# Euro symbol in Prawn table not showing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, utf-8

I have a problem in rails with displaying the euro symbol in a prawn table. I use prawn to offer my users the posibility to download pdf invoices.

```
pdf = Prawn::Document.new
[...]

invoice_data = [["Description", "Price", "Qty", "Total"]]

invoice_items.map do |item|
  pdf.font "#{Prawn::BASEDIR}/data/fonts/verdanab.ttf"
  pdf.font "#{Prawn::BASEDIR}/data/fonts/Verdana.ttf"
  invoice_data << ["","€ 10",1,"€ 10"]
end


pdf.table(invoice_data, :width => pdf.bounds.width,:cell_style => { :inline_format => true },:row_colors => ["FFFFFF", "DDDDDD"])
```

The problem is after i try to run this code i get this error and i couldn't get it to work otherwise...

```
invoices_pdf.rb:64: invalid multibyte char (US-ASCII)
invoices_pdf.rb:64: invalid multibyte char (US-ASCII)
invoices_pdf.rb:64: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting ']'
  invoice_data << ["","€ 10",1,"€ 10"]
                         ^
```

I saw the tips on the prawn google group but those were for pdf.text elements and this is a table and i can't figure it out....

Thanks!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To help others out.

I got an answer from "James Healy" on the prawn google group:

> To include non-ascii characters in a ruby 1.9 file you must add the
>   following to the first line of the file:
>
> ```
> # coding: utf-8
> ```
>
> Cheers
>
> James

Didn't know that.

Thanks.